# Checkbox does not work when clicking on it

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-5

I change this code:
[Demo1](https://codepen.io/El7raq/pen/NWprVrR)

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <span class="nav-switch" href="#">
     <span class="language" id="eg">EG</span>
       <label class="switch">
           <input type="checkbox">
           <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    <span  class="language" id="ar">AR</span>
  </span>
</li>
```

To this code:
[Demo2](https://codepen.io/El7raq/pen/NWprVdb)

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <span class="nav-switch" href="#">
     <span class="language" id="eg">EG</span>
       <a class="switch">
           <input type="checkbox">
           <span class="slider round"></span>
       </a>
    <span  class="language" id="ar">AR</span>
  </span>
</li>
```

To be able to take action when changing from one language to another using the checkbox but after making that change, the color of the checkbox does not change as in Demo1, I need to take action because I use PHP/Laravel

Comment: your code is invalid, you cannot wrap a link around an input element

Comment: Thank you for this information, do you have an idea how to solve this problem in order to be able to take the action? Thank you very much

Comment: it's not clear why did you change from demo1 (which is working) to demo2: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I want to change the site language, I want to take action so that I can change the language using one of the PHP libraries

Comment: it's unclear what do you expect to do. You could detect the state of the checkbox on change event (via JS), then you could set a cookie or make an ajax request depending on the value or make a redirect to the page translated. You didn't say what is the expected action. And what if you have a third language in the future?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, I sent this code to a friend who works as a backend developer, but he wanted to change the page language through one of the Laravel libraries instead of JS, I was not tried using ajax before, but I will search for how to use it, and unfortunately, I don't know the exact procedure to be expected. Maybe take the ```span "id"``` of the ```span``` that bears the name of the language to be changed to,

Comment: you are correct, maybe we need to add a third language, but the site is Arabic in origin, so the possibility of adding a third language is almost non-existent, but I will change the code so that it is a drop list and I can add any number of languages and thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You removed the `label` wrapper from the input which was doing the magic

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

and replace it with `a` tag as

```
 <a href="#" class="switch">
     <input type="checkbox">
     <span class="slider round"></span>
 </a>
```

For this to work you must wrap `input` around the `label` tag which targets the input inside it

Comment: Thanks for you, I know the problem now